# Pygame - Display variable on display window

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using Pygame and have figured out how to display text on the screen. But how would I get this to work for a variable, so instead of it displaying "Hello" it'll display my variable. For example, say I have a variable and I'd like to display it/any changes made to it on the display panel. So if my variable was 1, and if 1 was added to it, I'd like to display the changed variable.

```
#Dice random number generation
diceRoll = random.randrange(0, 5)

#Text through GUI
myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 18)

randNumLabel = myFont.render("You have rolled:", 1, black)
diceDisplay = myFont.render(diceRoll, 1, black)

screen.blit(randNumLabel, (520, 20))
screen.blit(diceDisplay, (520, 30))

pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where exactly is your problem? Your code does not display "Hello" anywhere.

The only problems I see are that the first argument of `Font.render` has to be a `str`, and you don't have any kind of loop, so the window closes immediately.

But this is easy to fix:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
black=(0,0,0)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
screen.fill((255,255,255))

#Dice random number generation
diceRoll = random.randrange(0, 5)

#Text through GUI
myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 18)

randNumLabel = myFont.render("You have rolled:", 1, black)
### pass a string to myFont.render
diceDisplay = myFont.render(str(diceRoll), 1, black)

screen.blit(randNumLabel, (520, 20))
screen.blit(diceDisplay, (520, 30))

### main loop
run = True
while run:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: The "Hello" was just an example, but i wanted the variable diceRoll to display as text